# Use kafkaListener with syncCommit, but they not work

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

I have an application that listens to a **Kafka** topic and reads 1 message from it in 1 thread. After reading a message, there is a certain logic, during which there are two options - everything is successful and a commit occurs call method *...acknowledge()* to offset the offset and move on to the next message, or everything is unsuccessful and this message must be read again and the offset is not committed (*...acknowledge()* is not called)
But now for some reason I can’t read the same message and always move on to the next one, although I don’t call *...acknowledge()* and it seems like the offset for my *groupId* should be on the same message.

I'm using spring-kafka and the following settings are specified:

```
spring.kafka.consumer.enable-auto-commit=false
spring.kafka.consumer.auto-offset-reset=earliest
spring.kafka.consumer.max-poll-records=1
```

And I programmatically set the settings:

```
...setGroupId("test");
...setSyncCommits(true);
...setAckMode(ContainerProperties.AckMode.MANUAL_IMMEDIATE);
...setConcurrency(1);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Kafka consumer keeps track of offsets in-memory, without resorting to the offsets saved on the cluster. The cluster offsets are only used when the consumer is connecting (or otherwise doesn't know the offset).

You need to either retry in-memory, or manually `seek()` the consumer to the previous position.

Comment: @Kayar, can I use offset offset on the side of the cluster? Do not store this information in the application of the application?

Answer (score 1):

Throw an exception and the default error handler will perform the seek and redeliver the message; you can customize the retry count and delay between retries.

See https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#annotation-error-handling

Comment: 1)I experimented, in version 2.7.7 the first repeated attempt worked after 45 minutes, and the second after 30, interesting)
Thank you, your answer and raising the version helped, now it works correctly. Unless the class that Extends Retrytopicconfigurationsuport came to add @enablesheDuling.
Is there a restriction on the time of delay? Can I set 30 minutes, 1 hour, 4 hours to start repeated processing?

2)So I thought about this, thanks for confiring my thought

Comment: When extending `Retrytopicconfigurationsupport` you can either add `@EnableScheduling` or add a `TaskScheduler` `@Bean`. When using non-blocking retries; there are no threads blocked, so you can set the delay to whatever you want; the container is simply paused for that time and we continue to poll the consumer, receiving no records. With blocking retries, the maximum delay must be less than `max.poll.interval.ms` to avoid a rebalance.